# Order rows by multiple cases on same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this structure

```
        |   start_at
----------------------
record1 |  2016-01-20 
record2 |  2016-01-15 
record3 |  2016-01-22 
record4 |  2016-01-10
```

Let`s say that the current date it`s 2016-01-19

I want to first get the records that have start_at greater than the current date and order them by start_at ASC.

Then I want to get the records that have start_at smaller than the current date and order them by start_at DESC.

So the results should be like this:

```
        |   start_at
----------------------
record1 |  2016-01-20
record3 |  2016-01-22
record2 |  2016-01-15
record4 |  2016-01-10
```

How can I do this?

I tried doing like this, but no success:

`ORDER BY start_at >= NOW() ASC, start_at < NOW() DESC`

Comment: Maybe split this into 2 queries ordered the way you want and concatenate them with a union?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close, with the multiple keys for the `order by`:

```
ORDER BY (start_at >= NOW()) desc,
         (case when start_at >= NOW() then start_at end) asc,
         (case when start_at < NOW() then start_at end) desc
```

The first condition puts the future dates first.  How?  The expression `start_at >= NOW()` returns a boolean.  True values are "1" and false "0", so `desc` but the future values first.  The other two keys handle the ordering within each group.